# Offline Files (CSC) on Windows RT

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-networking, windows-rt, offline-files

Windows RT does not have the *Offline Files* service. The Sync Center is also gone.

Can it be enabled somehow? or can anyone recommend a replacement? My options are very limited on Windows 8.1 RT.

The only thing it seems Microsoft is offering is something called [Work Folders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265974.aspx). These are only supported in Windows 8.1. I really want a more generic solution so that I can access files on OS X and Linux (like a samba share).

Answer (score -1):

Windows 8 RT does not have Sync Center or Offline Files.

Windows 8.1 RT has instead more SkyDrive sync capabilities, including Offline Files by right-clicking a file or folder in the SkyDrive folder and selecting `Make available offline`.

For more info, see for example these articles :
[How To Keep Your Files Synced With SkyDrive In Windows 8.1](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-keep-your-files-synced-with-skydrive-in-windows-8-1/)
[How to Access SkyDrive Files Offline in Windows 8.1](http://blog.laptopmag.com/skydrive-offlin-windows-8-1)

SkyDrive can be installed for other operating systems :

[Set Up Microsoft SkyDrive for Mac](http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/Set-Up-Microsoft-Skydrive-For-Mac.htm)
[SkyDrive integration in GNOME 3.6](http://debarshiray.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/gnome-documents-skydrive/)

SkyDrive is also accessible in the browser via SkyDrive.com .

Comment: This question was not about the SkyDrive service.

Comment: This may not be what you wish to hear, but there is no way to force Windows RT to be anything else than Windows RT. One cannot even run third-party applications on Windows RT unless they were specifically compiled for it. Windows RT is a trap with no other issue than those provided by Microsoft, and SkyDrive is the only built-in solution for sharing files.